# The latest version of Java for DrJava.org

Tags: java, drjava

When I visit java.com it says that the latest version is Version 8 (Updated 251) and when I visit Oracle it says the latest version of jdk is 14.0, which one of these do I need to install to run java codes on Dr Java?

Comment: DrJava's website says [the baseline is Java 2](http://www.drjava.org/run.shtml) so either.

Comment: java.com provides the Java *plugin,* which was dropped after 1.8. That doesn't imply that the latest version of ***Java*** is 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Other versions may of course work, but it seems Corretto 8 is the officially recommended version.

From the [DrJava web page](http://www.drjava.org/):

> We strongly recommend installing the Amazon Corretto 8 distribution of Open JDK 8 available from the [Amazon Corretto download page](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/) because this distribution appears to be the most comprehensive and best supported formulation of Open Java 8.

Comment: Thank you. Aren't jdk and java the same thing? if the latest version of jdk is 14.0 should the latest version of java be 14.0 as well? To write java programs and run them successfully on any IDE (DrJava)  do we install jdk (version 14) or the java (version 8)?

Comment: "Java" is a generic name that's used to mean all sorts from the JRE, JDK, the language itself, sometimes even the JVM. The JDK is what you need to compile & run Java program such as those that you write with DrJava. The latest version is indeed 14.0, but DrJava seems to recommend using version 8, so that's what I'd recommend. By all means try 14 if you want to, but bear in mind it may not work (well, or at all.)

Answer (score -1):

Kindly note that IDE dose not depend on JDK , so you can download any JDK with your current IDE , but the only differ is feature that you will get with JDK version

hope is clear